# CMake: best structure when migrating microrepositories to a monorepo?

Tags: c++, cmake

At the early stage of our development, we have created micro-repositories, to be able to deeply modify repositories while minimizing interference with each other's work. 
Now that we have a fairly stable version of our codebase, we want to merge some of the micro-repositories into a monorepo. That will ease the users' experience while building from source, as well as the deployment phase.

All our micro-repositories are built with CMake, and each of them obviously defines a `project()`. They also have 'internal' dependencies: some of the micro-repositories is built first and then used by the others with `find_package()`.

```
RepoA
  |-- CMakeLists.txt 
       | project(RepoA)

RepoB
  |-- CMakeLists.txt 
       | project(RepoB)
       | find_package(RepoA)

RepoC
  |-- CMakeLists.txt 
       | project(RepoC)
       | find_package(RepoA)
       | find_package(RepoB)
```

While migrating them into a monorepo, the first option that came to my mind is moving each of them into a subdirectory, then adding `add_subdirectory()` to the root `CMakeLists.txt` file to build them. In the first instance, I would define a global project by using `project()` in the root `CMakeLists.txt` file, and I would also keep the `project()` definition in subdirectories.

```
Monorepo/
  |-- CMakeLists.txt
       | project(Monorepo)
       | add_subdirectory(RepoA)
       | add_subdirectory(RepoB)
       | add_subdirectory(RepoC)
  |-- RepoA/
       |-- CMakeLists.txt 
           | project(RepoA)
  |-- RepoB/
       |-- CMakeLists.txt 
           | project(RepoB)
           | find_package(RepoA)
  |-- RepoC/
       |-- CMakeLists.txt 
           | project(RepoC)
           | find_package(RepoA)
           | find_package(RepoB)
```

Now the question is: is that a good choice? Would you advise having a global project and multiple sub-projects, all of them defined through the use of the CMake `project()` command? Are there better strategies?

And also, would this strategy have drawbacks?

Many thanks for your kind help!

Comment: I think that a monorepo done like that is fine. However, at the border of a `project()` call maybe I'd keep `find_package` around, even if its defined to do nothing for those repo.

Comment: In CMake there is no single project structure which overcomes every other. Each strategy has advantages and disadvantages. You have choose one strategy, so just follow it.

Comment: Thanks, @GuillaumeRacicot. I'm working just now on the monorepo and, concerning the `find_package()` command, I'm now finding that those calls give errors when used in the monorepo. I'm now investigating how to set internal dependencies properly.

Comment: Thanks, @Tsyvarev. Yes, you are right: it all depends on the specific situation and use-case. But I wanted to verify if there were strategies that were considered as "best practices" more than others.

Comment: "I wanted to verify if there were strategies that were considered as "best practices" more than others." - There are many of them ... or none ... it very **depends** from the understanding of the words "best" and "more than others". Do you consider e.g. Boost as an example of good project structure? What about QT? Your whole question post is full of **subjective** questions: "is that a good choice?", "Would you advice?", "Are there better strategies?". As you have found, `find_package` doesn't work easily with `add_subdirectory` approach. But there are workarounds. Is it bad or good?